# Jinja2 access last variable with key

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have following dictionary

```
myarr:
  - name: test1
  - name: test2
  - name: test3
```

In my ansible, I want to do following:

```
lineinfile: dest=testfile line="var = {{myarr|last ['name']}}"
```

However, I am not able to figure out how to access last variable and then use `name` key. I cannot modify my dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use parentheses

```
var = {{(myarr|last)['name']}}
```

**`playbook.yml`**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
      myarr:
        - name: test1
        - name: test2
        - name: test3
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "var = {{(myarr|last)['name']}}"
```

**`$ ansible-playbook playbook.yml`**

```
PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "var = test3"
}
```

Comment: @SztupY, i've tested on 2.0.1.0 and it works. Did you get any error messages?

Comment: might have messed it up somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

I've tried various options trying to do it in one line using the `last`, `map`, `attr` and similar filters, but all failed.

Using an intermediate variable works however (using ansible 2.0.1.0):

**`group_vars/all.yml`**:

```
myarr:
  - name: test1
  - name: test2
  - name: test3
```

**`play.yml`**:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    - lastarr: "{{myarr|last}}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "var = {{lastarr['name']}}"
```

**`$ ansible-playbook -i localhost, play.yml`**:

```
PLAY [localhost] ***************************************************************

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "var = test3"
}

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0
```